# no main methods, applets, or Midlets found in file jgrasp

Tags: java, file, exception, program-entry-point

In my code I have placed a main method in it. The program compiles on jgrasp with no errors. But it keeps giving me a message that says :"no main methods, applets, or Midlets found in file jgrasp"

```
  import java.io.*;
  public class XOREncyrption
  {//start of  class

  public static void Main(String [] args)
  {//start of main
  File f = new File("data.txt");
  File g = new File("key.txt");



  try
  {

     FileInputStream r = new FileInputStream(f);
     FileInputStream x = new FileInputStream(g);
     byte [] me = new byte [(int)f.length()];
     byte [] we =new byte [(int)g.length()];


   int why = r.read(me);
   int where =x.read(we);

      //input.close();

  }
   catch(FileNotFoundException e)
  {
     System.out.print("No file");
  }
  catch(IOException e)
  {
     System.out.println("error");
  }


  }//end of main
  }//end of class
```

If anyone can figure out why the code is telling me there is no main method when there is one made, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The entry method must be named "main" (lower case 'm').